# array search not working

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i have got the folowing code.

```
$coauthors = get_post_meta( $post_id, "coAuthors" );

print_r($coauthors);
```

ok result from print_r is

```
Array ( [0] => 78 ) Array ( [0] => 78 )
```

now my user id is 78 so it should return true with the follow code but it doesnt.

```
$key = array_search( 78, $coauthors );

     if($key) { 

     return true;

     }else{

     echo "no"; 

     }
```

Why do i always get no where am i going wrong what the best way to do this???

Thanks

> 

### Im still getting issues here is my function.

```
   add_action('is_true','isdAuthorTrue');

    function isdAuthorTrue( $post_id ) { 

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
    return;

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

         $coauthors = get_post_meta( $post_id, "coAuthors" );

         $key = array_search( $current_user->ID, $coauthors );
         $key = 0;
         if($key !== false) {

           return true;

         } else {

             return false;
         }


        }
```

and then i am trying to run this in the loop.

```
if(do_action( 'is_true', $post->ID )){

    echo "yes";

}else{

    echo "no";
}
```

help???

Comment: See the big red warning in the [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) documentation :-)

Comment: Heh I was just about to paste that warning in :)

Comment: Remove that `$key = 0;` from the code for starters. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$key = 0;
```

That results in false.

You should check for key like this:

```
if($key !== false) {
    // do sth with it
} else {
    // does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because no entry in $coauthors has the value 78. $coauthors is an array of arrays, and one of the sub-arrays has the value 78 in it.

So you'd need to search all the sub-arrays.

edit: hm, you sure your print_r results in a printout that looks like that? Looks odd...

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the key value will be 0 because that is the index in the array where 78 is a value.  Thus says `if($key)` will fail when $key = 0, even if $key is a valid array index.

To check for validity, what you should be doing is something like the following

```
if (in_array(78, $coauthors)) {
    $key = array_search(78, $coauthors);
    // do what you want with $key and the $coauthors array
}
```